# How to change the color of dynamically generated text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm facing difficulty in changing the color of the dynamically generated text box on click event. The idea is that if user would like to update text in the text box, the color of the text box should be changed. 
Here is my code:
The below code actually fetches data from database and display it to the user

```
echo '<td>'.
     '<input type = "text" class="form-control" onclick="changeColor()" disabled = "disabled" 
     id ="'.$row["ID"].'"  name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].
     ']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
```

On Click event, I would like to change the color of the text box,
here is my attempt:

```
changeColor () { this.style.color = '#cc0000'; }
```

I have integrated this code in the above line, however it is giving me an error.

> ERROR: TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Comment: How is the event bound on dynamically generated textbox?

Comment: you want to change background color or border color??

Comment: Also add the error description with **complete** code

Comment: Please show your error.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Anything would work, background or border color, just want the user to know that you've started editing. Can you help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simpler by binding to the click event on inputs and remove the inline `onClick()`...

```
$('input').on('click', function(){

    $(this).css({ 'border': '1px solid black', 'background-color': 'white' });
})
```

And by making use of the 'data-' attribute, your can isolate which inputs you wish to bind to...

`<input data-myattribute=""` blah blah blah `/>`

Then you could use

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[data="myattribute"]', function(){

    $(this).css({ 'border': '1px solid black', 'background-color': 'white' });
})
```

**EDIT FROM FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

HTML

```
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

JS

```
$('#update').on('click', function(){

    // Gets the input elements you're interested in
    var items = $(document).find('input[data="myattribute"]');
    // Loops through each jQuery object and you can apply whatever property values you want
    items.each(function(){
        $(this).css({ 'border': '1px solid blue', 'background-color': 'red' });
    });

});
```

Comment: I'd recommend to add class instead of setting inline styles

Comment: Yes I would do to but that wasn't the OP's question :-/

Comment: @AdamJeffers may I ask another question, if I have to remove this feature on click of another button say "update", how do I do that, any method that can set it to the original settings?

Comment: Ill update my answer with some code example but what do you mean by "remove this feature"? Do you mean when you click the update button, all the border and background colours change back to an original colour?

Answer (score 1):

Change the event handler to send the current context `this` to the event handler.

```
onclick="changeColor(this)"
```

And in JS use the element context and set the properties on it.

```
function changeColor (el) {
    el.style.color = '#cc0000';
}
```

---

I will recommend to use class instead of setting inline styles.

CSS:

```
.warning {
    color: #c00;
}
```

JS:

```
el.classList.add('warning');
```

---

As jQuery is included on the page, I'd recommend to use it to bind event.

```
$('input.form-control').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('warning');
});
```

---

To change the color of the element on focus

```
input:focus, input:active {
    border-color: #c00;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this worked, but I'm marking another one as official answer coz it went well with the entire code and gave me flexibility. thanks.

Comment: @user4943236 Welcome! glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

First give a class to your input, may be `Txt1`

If you want to do it on `click()`,

```
echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control Txt1" onclick="changeColor()" disabled = "disabled" id ="'.$row["ID"].'"  name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
```

Style

```
.background{
     background-color : #90EE90;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click",".Txt1",function() {
   $(this).addClass('background');
 });

 $(document).on("blur",".Txt1",function() {
   $(this).removeClass('background');
 });

});
```

If you want for on focus(), change code like this,

```
$(document).on("focus",".Txt1",function() {
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvJzX/361/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get event from dynamically generated element, you need to bind event start with document object.

e.g.

```
$(document).on("click",".className or #id" ,function(e){
});
```

For input type use blur event or click event as per your requirement

```
$(document).on("click/blur","input[type="text"],function(e){
    $(this).css({'color': '#cc0000});
});
```